# Prove convergence to zero of $f(t + x) - f(x)$ in the $L^p$-norm

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces

I'd like to show that $\Vert f(t + x) - f(x) \Vert_p \rightarrow 0$ as $t \rightarrow 0$, where $f \in L^p([0, \infty))$ and $\Vert \cdot \Vert_p$ is the usual norm on $L^p$. First I thought of using the Lebesgue-Dominated-Convergence theorem but I can't quite see how to estimate the function $f(t + x) - f(x)$.

Any hint is appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: The property under consideration states that the family of contraction
operators {${U(t),t≥ 0}$}, where $(U(t)f)(x)=f(x+t)$, is strongly
continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**. Use that $C^0_c([0,\infty))$ is dense in $L^p([0,\infty))$ and prove your claim first for a continuous function with compact support (by dominated convergence) and than use the denseness and approximate an arbritrary $f \in L^p$ by an $g \in C^0_c$.

Comment: I think I can even use Banach-Steinhaus at this point, right?

Comment: What if $p=\infty$? The collection of continuous functions with compact support is not dense in $L^{\infty}$, so one cannot apply the same argument in that case.